# Doctrine Combining count, grouped select

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table

```
ID    | Name  | enabled1 |  count1  | enabled2 | count2
1     | John  |     1    |    3     |    0     |   4
2     | John  |     1    |    2     |    1     |   2
3     | Mike  |     0    |    7     |    0     |   3
4     | Simon |     1    |    3     |    1     |   2
5     | John  |     0    |    2     |    1     |   7
6     | Mike  |     0    |    2     |    0     |   1
7     | Marco |     1    |    6     |    1     |   6
8     | John  |     1    |    9     |    0     |   2
9     | Marco |     0    |    4     |    0     |   1
```

And this is my doctrine function:

```
public function countCombined() : array
{
   $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
   $qb->select('u.name, COUNT(u.id), SUM(u.count1) as count1, SUM(u.count2) as count2');

   $qb->where(
       $qb->expr()->andX(
          $qb->expr()->eq('u.enabled1', ':enabled'),
              $qb->expr()->eq('u.enabled2', ':enabled'), // this should not be here
       )
   );

   $qb->setParameter('enabled', '1');

   $qb->groupBy('u.name');

   return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

the function should give me an array of grouped names with sum of count1 if enabled1 is active, the same is for count2 and enabled2. But my idea is if it is possiable to make it in one function or do i need to make another one?

it should give me something like this back:

```
Name  | count1  | count2 | NamesCounted
John  |   14    |    8   |     4
Mike  |   0     |    0   |     2
Simon |   3     |    2   |     1
Marco |   6     |    6   |     2
```

counts all of the grouped named, and counts1 when enabled1 is active, counts2 if enabled2 is active.

Thank you.

Comment: What does the current query output shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for :

```
select 
  Name,
  sum(case when enabled1=1 then count1 end) as count1,
  sum(case when enabled2=1 then count2 end) as count2,
  count(id) as NamesCounted
from myTable
group by Name
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2b389186cc55cf2ca2e85dd8d134528b)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could i count the ids of the enabled1 and 2? something like sum(case when enabled1=1 then id end) as count1,

Comment: You might want : sum(case when enabled1=1 then 1 end)

Comment: It works fine in pure sql , i tried that but in doctrine it gives the same value back.  i did something like this         $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
        $qb->select(
            'u.name,
                   COUNT(case when u.enabled1=1 then 1 else 0 end) as count1,
                   COUNT(case when u.enabled2=1 then 1 else 0 end) as count2,
                   COUNT(u.id) as namesCounted'
        );

Comment: Use sum not count !

Comment: Or you could have used count but you would have to remove "else 0" ;)

Comment: I can't remove else, doctrine asks for it and throws an error

Comment: Ok that's perfect then :) Great job !